# show data in listview from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am creating a listview activity to retrieve data from sqlite database
database class as..

```
package com.example.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String TABLE_STUDENT = "students";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
    public static final String COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";

    public static final String COLUMN_ROLLNO = "_rollno";
    public static final String COLUMN_STUDENTNAME = "studentname";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT = "contact";  
    SQLiteDatabase data=this.getWritableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase data1 =this.getReadableDatabase();
    Product product;
    Detail detail;
    public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {       
        try {
            // Create table Place
            String CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                    TABLE_STUDENT + "("
                    + COLUMN_ROLLNO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_STUDENTNAME 
                    + " TEXT," + COLUMN_CONTACT + " INTEGER" + ");";

            db.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE);
            // Create table Reminder
            String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                      TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
                      + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME 
                      + " TEXT," + COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" + ");";           
              db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);        
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler Oncreate SQLException",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(se));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler Oncreate Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
        Log.d("database","table created");      
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
        // Drop table Place
                    String placeTableDropQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
                    db.execSQL(placeTableDropQuery);
                    // Drop table Reminder
                    String ReminderTableDropQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
                            + TABLE_STUDENT;
                    db.execSQL(ReminderTableDropQuery);
                    // Upgrade database
                    onCreate(db);
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    Log.v("DatabaseHandler onUpgrade SQLException",
                            Log.getStackTraceString(se));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("DatabaseHandler onUpgrade Exception",
                            Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }
    }   
    public String addProduct(Product product) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.getProductName());
            values.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY, product.getQuantity());
            db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
            db.close();
            return "Record insert succussfully...";
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler insertStudentRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(se));
            return se.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler insertStudentRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return e.getMessage();
        } finally{
            db.close();
        }        
}   
    public String addProduct(Detail product) {      
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_STUDENTNAME, product.getName());
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT, product.getNo());
            db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT, null, values);
            db.close();
            return "Record insert succussfully...";
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(se));
            return se.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHandler insertTeacherRecord Exception",
                    Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return e.getMessage();
        } finally{
            db.close();
        }
    }
    public Product findProduct(String productname) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";      
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);       
        Product product = new Product();        
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            product.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            product.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
            product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            product = null;
        }
            db.close();
        return product;
    }
    public Detail findDetail(int studentname) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ROLLNO + " =  \"" + studentname + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);       
        Detail detail = new Detail();       
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            detail.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            detail.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            detail.setNo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            detail= null;
        }
            db.close();
        return detail;
    }   
    public boolean deleteProduct(String productname) {      
        boolean result = false;     
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);       
        Product product = new Product();        
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            product.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(product.getID()) });
            cursor.close();
            result = true;
        }
            db.close();
        return result;
    }   
    public boolean deleteDetail(String studentname) {       
        boolean result = false;     
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + " WHERE " + COLUMN_STUDENTNAME + " =  \"" + studentname + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);       
        Detail detail = new Detail();       
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            detail.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            db.delete(TABLE_STUDENT, COLUMN_ROLLNO + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(detail.getID()) });
            cursor.close();
            result = true;
        }
            db.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

create activity which has button and on button click mylistactivity is show
activity as..

```
package com.example.database;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.database.R.string;    
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;    

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    MyDBHandler db;     
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        retrive();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        db =new MyDBHandler(MyListActivity.this);
    }    
    private void retrive() {
        ArrayList<String>namelist= new ArrayList<String>();
        int ii;
        //ArrayList<String>studentno = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sd.query(db.TABLE_STUDENT, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        ii=cursor.getColumnIndex("studentname");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            namelist.add(cursor.getString(ii));
            //studentno.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }
        ArrayList<String>combimelist=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<namelist.size();i++){
            combimelist.add(namelist.get(i));
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListActivity.this,R.layout.mylist, combimelist);
    }
}
```

and layout to show this as

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">


</TextView>
```

it show error as..

```
05-21 05:08:53.823: I/Choreographer(1887): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-21 05:08:54.043: D/AndroidRuntime(1887): Shutting down VM
05-21 05:08:54.043: W/dalvikvm(1887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.database/com.example.database.MyListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at com.example.database.MyListActivity.retrive(MyListActivity.java:30)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at com.example.database.MyListActivity.onCreate(MyListActivity.java:21)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-21 05:08:54.363: E/AndroidRuntime(1887):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you also have a question ?

Comment: yes it doesn't show list view

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't show the list view due to the exception that you have demonstrated.  Please ensure you include the actual question you are wanting answered so we can help further.

Comment: @MonikaKrail `what exactly not working`  post only the relevant part !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly intialize **db** then call **retrive()** method:

Replace:

```
retrive();
setListAdapter(adapter);
db =new MyDBHandler(MyListActivity.this);
```

To:

```
db =new MyDBHandler(MyListActivity.this);
retrive();
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @NehaAgarwal you don't deserve upvote because the code is badly formatted.